# how to prevent series values scalling to 100% range of Qt chart axis?

Tags: qt, charts, range, qt5, axis

I am creating the chart from database values (two series). The values are in the range 0 - 1. When axis are created by command:

```
chart->createDefaultAxes();
```

Then graph looks like this (note the maximum value 0,941):

[image]

I would like to have the range of Y axis from 0 to 1 exactly. But when the axes are created explicitly

```
QValueAxis *axisY = new QValueAxis(chart);
chart->setAxisY(axisY);
axisY->setRange(0,1);
axisY->setTickCount(11);
```

then the values are "stretched" to 100% of range and graph is showing unreal values. Both lines have the maximum 1.0 which is not what is in database.

[image]

How to prevent the values "stretching"?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. When axes are attached using commands below everything is working:

```
chart->setAxisX(axisX,chart->series().at(0));
chart->setAxisX(axisX,chart->series().at(1));
chart->setAxisY(axisY,chart->series().at(0));
chart->setAxisY(axisY,chart->series().at(1));
```

But it is not clear for me, why the following simple commands are not working:

```
chart->setAxisX(axisX);
chart->setAxisY(axisY);
```

I was expecting that if series is not specified then axis will be used for all series implicitly. And if axes are not automatically used, why the values are "stretched"? This is not expected behaviour...